# In SQL Server what is the most efficient way to determine which weekday and week in the month my data is for

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am trying to compare data across months, however the data is highly day specific so I need to compare the 1st Monday of June against the 1st Monday of July, then the 1st Tuesday and so on. I will answer below with the query I use but would like to know if the query will be remotely efficient or if there is a better way. Also I'd like a quick logic check from an outsider to offer some reassurance that the query will work in the way I intend in all circumstances.

Apologies for the convoluted title hopefully it will make more sense once you see the query, if any editors have an idea for a clearer title please make suggestions.

Query:

```
select 
[start time],
case 
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Sunday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Sunday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Sunday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Sunday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Sunday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 2 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Monday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 2 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Monday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 2 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Monday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 2 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Monday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 2 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Monday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 3 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Tuesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 3 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Tuesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 3 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Tuesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 3 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Tuesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 3 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Tuesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 4 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Wednesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 4 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Wednesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 4 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Wednesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 4 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Wednesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 4 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Wednesday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 5 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Thursday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 5 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Thursday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 5 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Thursday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 5 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Thursday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 5 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Thursday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 6 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Friday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 6 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Friday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 6 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Friday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 6 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Friday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 6 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Friday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Saturday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 16  then '2nd Saturday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 15 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 24  then '3rd Saturday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 23 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 31  then '4th Saturday'
when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 7 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) > 30 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 32  then '5th Saturday'
else 'Other' end as [day]

from inboundcallsview
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is the one which does this in very less instructions..In this i would go for  a [Calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) .we can populate it once,occupies some hard disk space and thats it..

We can use this to complete various tasks..

coming to your example,if we want to know when friday falls over the years,we can just simply query like below

[image]

Comment: All the information he needs is available via date formulae though, should only need a calendar for non-standard info such as company period ends etc.

Comment: This calculation also gets simple ...when DATEPART(DW,[start time]) = 1 and DATEPART(dd,[Start Time]) < 8 then '1st Sunday'

Answer (score 0):

You can use calendar table:

```
DECLARE @dateStart date = '2016-01-01',
        @dateFinish date = '2016-12-31'

;WITH dates as (
SELECT CAST(@dateStart as datetime) d
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,d)
FROM dates
WHERE d < @dateFinish
), cte AS  (
SELECT  CAST(d as date) as D,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(d),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,d) ORDER BY d) as seq
FROM dates)

SELECT *
FROM cte
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

F.e. you need all first Mondays you need to add WHERE statement to SELECT FROM cte:

```
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D) = 2 AND seq = 1
```

That will give you:

```
D           seq
2016-01-04  1
2016-02-01  1
2016-03-07  1
2016-04-04  1
2016-05-02  1
2016-06-06  1
2016-07-04  1
2016-08-01  1
2016-09-05  1
2016-10-03  1
2016-11-07  1
2016-12-05  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @DAT as datetime;
DECLARE @SUFFIX as nvarchar(50) = 'stndrdthththth';

SET @DAT = '20160801';

while @dat < '20170101'
BEGIN 

SELECT @dat,
      CAST((DATEPART(d,@DAT) - 1) / 7 + 1 as nvarchar(1))
      + SUBSTRING(@SUFFIX,1 + 2*(FLOOR(DATEPART(d,@DAT) - 1) / 7),2) 
      + ' ' 
      +  DATENAME(dw,@DAT);

SET @dat = @dat + 1

END
```

your query will become

```
select 
[start time],
CAST((DATEPART(d,@start time) - 1) / 7 + 1 as nvarchar(1))
  + SUBSTRING('stndrdthththth',1 + 2*(FLOOR(DATEPART(d,@start time) - 1) / 7),2) 
  + ' ' 
  +  DATENAME(dw,@start time) as [DAY]
 from inboundcallsview
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code much more readable by defining a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[OrdinalDate] 
(   
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS int   
AS   
-- Returns n if @date is the nth occcurence of that weekday in the month
BEGIN  
    IF DATEPART(dd,@date) <= 7 THEN RETURN 1 
    ELSE IF DATEPART(dd,@date) > 7 and DATEPART(dd,@date) <= 15 THEN RETURN 2
    [...]
END;  
GO
```

And then you can compare like this:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM table t1
  INNER JOIN table t2 
    ON DATEPART(DW,t1.[start time]) = DATEPART(DW,t2.[start time])
   AND OrdinalDate(t1.[start time]) = OrdinalDate(t2.[start time])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this to get week list,

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 AS VARCHAR(2) ) + ' ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[start time])
```

If you need suffix after week number,

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 = 1 THEN '1st '
            WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 = 2 THEN '2nd '
            WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 = 3 THEN '3rd '
            WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 = 4 THEN '4th '
            WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,[start time]),0),[start time]) +1 = 5 THEN '5th '
        END 
        + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[start time])
```

Comment: if you had Friday 7th September, which Friday are you going to say it is using your formula?  Because that would be the first Friday, but your formula would say 2

Comment: not working, try '2016-07-07' - it says '2nd Thursday'

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
Case            
        WHEN CurrentMonth.WeekNum = 1 then Cast(CurrentMonth.WeekNum as nvarchar(1)) + 'st'
        WHEN CurrentMonth.WeekNum = 2 then Cast(CurrentMonth.WeekNum as nvarchar(1)) +'nd'
        WHEN CurrentMonth.WeekNum = 3 then Cast(CurrentMonth.WeekNum as nvarchar(1)) +'rd'
        WHEN CurrentMonth.WeekNum > 3 then Cast(CurrentMonth.WeekNum as nvarchar(1)) +'th'
        END,
        DATENAME(dw, [start time])          
 from inboundcallsview
 Cross Apply (Select (DATEPART(WEEK, [start time]) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,[start time]), 0))+ 1) WeekNum) AS CurrentMonth
```